# Question about covariant derivative on a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, connections

I'm reading about vector bundles from somme lecture notes written by Matvei Libine. He say that

> If $E \rightarrow M $ is a vector bundle, a covariant derivative on $E$ is a differential operator
> $$\nabla : \Gamma(E,M) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, T^*M \otimes E)$$
> wich satisfies the Leibniz's rule; that is, if $s \in \Gamma(E,M)$ and $f \in C^\infty (M)$, then
> $$\nabla(fs) = df \otimes s + f \nabla s. $$
> Note that a covariant derivative extends in a unique way to a map
> $$\nabla : \Omega^*(M,E) \rightarrow \Omega^{*+1}(M,E)$$
> that satisfies the Leibniz's rule: if $\alpha \in \Omega^k(M)$ and $\beta \in \Omega^*(E,M) 
> $, then
> $$ \nabla(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^k \alpha \wedge \nabla \beta$$.

Could someone please explain to me why and how does $\nabla$ extend in a unique way to a map $\nabla : \Omega^*(M,E) \rightarrow \Omega^{*+1}(M,E)$
that satisfies the Leibniz rule ?

Comment: The Leibniz rule for the connection in all degrees follows directly from the Leibniz rule for the exterior differential acting on smooth forms. It can be show that such an operator is unique by its defining properties.

Comment: @John,  thank you for your comment! But  still I don't understand Why can we extend $\nabla $ uniquely in all degrees. Could you elaborate further please ?